# Advanced Custom Fields - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

While using the *Custom Fields Plugin*, I cannot get it to return any data.

I have created a field group called `book_cover_thumbnail` which has one post linked to it. Can anyone see why the code below would not work?

```
<img src="<?php get_field('book_cover_thumbnail');?>" />
```

I get no errors at all, no white space.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are a) Echoing the field using either `the_field()` or `echo get_field()`, and b) this code is either within the wordpress loop like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`
<img src="<?php echo get_field('book_cover_thumbnail');?>" />
<?php end while; endif; ?>`
```

Or you add the post id to the `get_field()` function as a parameter:

```
$post_id = *your_post_ID_here*;
<img src="<?php echo get_field('book_cover_thumbnail', $post_id);?>" />
```

**Documentation:**

Using `get_field()`: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/

Using `the_field()`: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/

All Advanced Custom Fields Documentation: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/

Comment: This src URL only works if you have set your custom field to output as the URL, and not an object or an ID.

Comment: @MikeKormendy correct. For an object you would have to access the specific key you'd like, in this case I'm guessing something like `['url']`, or for a thumbnail sized image `['sizes']['thumb']['url']. For an ID, you'd have to use that ID to get the item you'd, most likely using a Wordpress function like wp_get_attachment($image_ID, 'thumbnail');, but without knowing the specific usage it's hard to say.

Answer (score 3):

Change get_field to the_field. Get field returns the value but doesn't echo it.

Alternatively, put an echo in front of the get field.

Comment: I tried the field first and also <img src="<?php echo get_field('book_cover_thumbnail');?>" />

Comment: Must be a simple answer but I cannot find it

Comment: Are you outside of the WordPress loop? If so you need to give the field commands the post id so they can retrieve your field

Comment: maybe I am? I am not too sure. my post type is books, could you show me what my code should look like ?

Comment: I just tried copying this video http://vimeo.com/21468614 where at the start the guy populates all the fields onto the page, mine does not do this

Comment: Cant see any rows in my sql database either.  hmmm

Comment: Is it possible to display all the values collected using acf form fields as a dashboard table ? I know to build forms , and collect data. but I want to output them as a dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late but also important nevertheless:

You can change the "Return Format" in Custom Fields -> Field Groups -> Return Format
You have the choice between value/label and both(array)

Maybe that could help you in this case